# Number theory problem (my solution included).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let n be a natural number greater than 1. We call a natural number $a>2$ ,$n-$decomposable if $a^n-2^n$ is divisible by all numbers of the form $a^d + 2^d$, where $d|n$ and $1\le d<n$. Find all $n$ for which there is an $n$-decomposable number.

I got:
$n$ is decomposable $\Leftrightarrow $ n is exactly the form $2^p$.

for "<=", divisors of $n=2^p$ is of form $d=2^q$ where $p\ge q$. since $a^n-2^n=(a-2)(a^1+2^1)(a^2+2^2)(a^4+2^4)(a^8+2^8)\dots(a^n+2^n)$, every $a^d+2^d$ is thereby a factor of $a^n-2^n$

for "=>", by contrapositive, assume $n$ is not $2^p$, then exist odd e and integer $d$ such that $n=de$. Let $b=a^d$ and hence $a^n=b^e$ , then $\frac{a^n-2^n}{a^d+2^d}=\frac{b^e-2^n}{b+2^d}$. by remainder theorem w.r.t. b, the "remainder" is $(-2^d)^e-2^n=-2^n-2^n=-2^{n+1}$.

Now we prove $-2^{n+1}$ is not divisible by $(b+2^d)$. Consider $a=3, b+2^d$ is odd, but $-2^{n+1}$ has only 1 odd factor, namely 1. So $n$ is not decomposable.

Comment: $a^n-2^n$ is not divisible by $a^n+2^n,$ as indicated by your factorization.

Comment: At the end, you write: “So $n$ is not decomposable.” You mean “there is no $n$-decomposable number.”

Comment: You can’t just consider $a=3,$ because the question is if some $a$ exists, not if it is true for all $a.$ So all you’ve show in the last step is that $3$ is not $n$-decomposable if $n$ is not a power of $2,$ but that doesn’t answer the cases $a=4,5,\dots.$ You can likewise show that odd $a>2$ can’t be $n$-decomposible, but you still need to show it for $a$ even.

Comment: If $a=4a_1,$ for some $a_1,$ then $$b^d+2^d=2^{2d}a_1^d+2^d=2^d(2^da_1+1),$$ and again you have an odd factor. So you are left showing the case $a=2a_2,$ with $a_2$ odd. For that, you need to know that $a_2^d+1$ is never a power of $2.$ If $d$ is even, you need that $m^2+1$ is never a power of $2.$ But $m^2+1\equiv 1,2\pmod 4,$ so $m^2+1$ is only a power of $2$ when $m=0,1.$ So finally you need the case $n$ odd, so there is no $d$ even, and $a=2a_2$ with $a_2$ odd.

Answer (score 1):

The latter part of your proof doesn’t work - it only shows that $3$ is not $n$-decomposible (or by extension, odd numbers are not $n$-decomposible.) It doesn’t answer whether there is any $n$-decomposible number.

And, indeed, there are other $n.$

If $n=p$ is an odd prime, then the only condition is $a+2$ being a factor of $a^p-2^p.$

So $a\equiv-2\pmod {a+2},$ in which case, by your argument, $$a^{p}-2^{p}\equiv -2^{p+1}\pmod {a+2}.$$

So we only need $a+2\mid 2^{p+1}.$ So $a=2^k-2$ for some $3\leq k\leq p+1.$

For example, $a=2^3-2=6$ is always $p$-decomposible for all odd primes $p$ because $6+2=8$ and $6^p-2^p$ is divisible by $8.$

$a=2^5-2=30$ is $p$-decomposible for prime $p\geq 5.$

It might be the case that $n$ prime or $n>1$ a power of $2$ are all the cases, I don’t know. Certainly, it seems harder to find $a$ when $n$ has a lot of odd factors.

When $n$ is even and not a power of $2,$ showing there are no $n$-reducible numbers reduces to the case of solving $m^2+1=2^k,$ which only has solutions $m=0,1,$ by looking modulo $4.$

So you are left with $n$ odd and not prime. Your proof again shows that $a=2b$ must be even. Then you need $b^d+1$ is a power of $2$ less than or equal to $2^{n+1-d}$ for all  factor $d<n.$ That seems unlikely for even $b+1$ and $b^p+1,$ but I don’t have the proof.

It certainly reduces the possible $a,$ since if $n>1$ is odd and not prime and $p$ is the is the smallest fact or $n,$ you get $b^{n/p}\leq 2^{n+p}$ or $b\leq 2^p\cdot 2^{p^2/n}\leq2^{1+\sqrt{n}}.$